# how to change IKImageBroswerView dragging image

Tags: image, cocoa, drag, ikimagebrowserview

I'm working on a program on Mac_OS 10.6 and later. The program language I'm using is Objc.

And I wonder what can I do to change the dragging image for an IKImageBrowserView? Is there any methods or delegates to change the default dragging image?

Thanks~

Sorry for my english.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I tried many methods and finally I came to a conclusion that this system action cannot be modified or removed, maybe there's some private methods I failed to find which can make it customizable.

Anyway, I change the design to avoid facing this embarrassing situation.